# Why does strtol require a pointer to a pointer rather than a single pointer?

Tags: c, strtol

Here's the prototype for the C standard library routine `strtol`:

```
long int strtol(const char* str, char** endptr, int base);
```

Typical usage:

```
const char* str = "123a";
char* endptr;
long int value = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);

if (*endptr)
  // Do something
else
  // Do something else
```

Why is it done this way? Why not pass the address of a local variable?

Example:

```
long int strtol(const char* str, char* endptr, int base);
```

Usage:

```
const char* str = "123a";
char end;
long int value = strtol(str, &end, 10);

if (end)
  // Do something
else
  // Do something else
```

I'm sure there is a logical reason for this design decision, but I don't quite see it.

Comment: What's the problem? The purpose of the second argument is to update a pointer to point to the end of the parsed sequence...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is using pointer to pointer for second parameter because it allows the caller to know exact position in string where parsing has stopped - and may be used to continue parsing the stream using some other method. Also, it permits to completely ignore it by supplying `NULL`.

Note that your proposed schema does not possess these useful properties.